# Blank white page when refreshing page [because of bootstrap css]

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

in my website panel everything is OK when using mozilla, chrome or other windows browsers.
But in mobile version (same browsers) when I refresh the page sometimes it gets white blank page. As I removed styles and javascripts I found out that the problem is with "bootstrap.css".
I have attached my code. The only styles I get from bs.css is "form-control" and buttons styles.
How can I fix this?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <title>Login</title>


    <!-- Bootstrap Core Css -->
    <link href="plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Waves Effect Css -->
    <link href="plugins/node-waves/waves.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Animation Css -->
    <link href="plugins/animate-css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />

    <!-- Custom Css -->
    <link href="css/login/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body class="login-page">
    <div class="login-box">
        <div class="logo">
            <h1>login</h1></a>
            <a href="index.php"><small>welcome</small></a>
        </div>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="body">
                <!-- Login users -->
                <form id="login_user" name="login_user" method="POST" action="funcs/check.php">
                    <div class="msg">please enter your login info</div>
                    <div class="input-group">

                        <div class="form-line">
                            <input name="logina_username" id="logina_username" type="text" class="form-control" maxlength="50" placeholder="username" autofocus />
                        </div>
                        <span id="name_status" class="status"></span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group">

                        <div class="form-line">
                            <input name="logina_pass" id="logina_pass" type="password" class="form-control" maxlength="50" placeholder="password" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <button class="btn btn-block btn-lg bg-orange waves-effect" type="submit">login</button>

                    <div class="m-t-25 m-b--5 align-center">
                        <a href="index.php" id="a-black">back to Home</a>
                    </div>
                </form>
                <!-- /Register form for users -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Jquery Core Js -->
    <script src="plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core Js -->
    <script src="plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

    <!-- Waves Effect Plugin Js -->
    <script src="plugins/node-waves/waves.js"></script>

    <!-- Validation Plugin Js -->
    <script src="plugins/jquery-validation/jquery.validate.js"></script>
    <!-- Custom Js -->
    <script src="js/admin.js"></script>
    <script src="js/form-validation.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is a framework for responsive, and in your html code you dont use bootstrap classe..
So to ensure that everything is right..you should only open a developer tools in chrome and then use mobile mode...then inspect your html tags into page to check wich applied classes on an element

Comment: its rights, I didn't use bootstrap on all elements but have you any idea why when I remove bootstrap.css link it works well?